# continously add to an objects key value in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am running a loop over some data. I have an object with a key value message. Every time I loop over my array I want to append to this objects key value, I tried using spread operator but not having any luck

```
  const arr1 = [
    "keith",
    "kelly",
    "ed",
    "shelby"
]

const arr2 = [
    "Parker",
    "Morgan",
    "Arnold",
    "Suski",
    "Parks"
]

const addToObjectsMessageKey = arr1.map((name) => {
 let obj = {}
    arr2.forEach((lastName) => { return {...obj, message: ...obj.message + name}})
 return obj
})

console.log(addToObjectsMessageKey)
```

expected output

```
addObjectsToMessageKey = [
{ message: "Parker Morgan Arnold Suski Parks" },
{ message: "Parker Morgan Arnold Suski Parks" },
{ message: "Parker Morgan Arnold Suski Parks" },
{ message: "Parker Morgan Arnold Suski Parks" },
]
```

Comment: Unclear what you're trying to achieve. You want `arr1.length` times the concatenated output of `arr2` in an object array? `arr1.map(_ => ({message: arr2.join(' ')}))`

Comment: Your code has an error *`SyntaxError: expected expression, got '...'"`*

Comment: also `arr2.forEach((lastName) => { return {`  does nothing, since the returned value in a forEach is a GNDN

Comment: you seem to be overcomplicating your code, to get what you want is a case of `const addToObjectsMessageKey = arr1.map(() => ({message: arr2.join(' ')}));`

Comment: I asked the question with better detail here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71658030/loop-over-string-add-words-to-string-return-string

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to overwrite the arr1 elements to an object with all the elements on the arr2 joined by space, you can simplify this using arr.join [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) instead of forEach

```js
const arr1 = ["keith", "kelly", "ed", "shelby"];

const arr2 = ["Parker", "Morgan", "Arnold", "Suski", "Parks"];

const addToObjectsMessageKey = arr1.map(() => {
  return {
    message: arr2.join(" ")
  };
});

console.log(addToObjectsMessageKey);
```

Here is a codeSandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-mestorf-tlhkh2?file=/src/index.js:0-248

Is this what you want?

Comment: I asked it better with more details here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71658030/loop-over-string-add-words-to-string-return-string

Comment: I see what you need, I added my go-to solution for those cases, Regex