# Replace words found in string

Tags: javascript, arrays, replace

Im trying to replace words in string with matched key and index position without removing the other words.

My desired output is: hey HI hey HELLO

What i've tried so far...

```js
var data = {
  items: ["item", "HI", "item2"],
  moreitems: ["moreitem", "moreitem1", "HELLO"]
}
var str = "hey #items1 hey #moreitems2";

var newStr = '';
var match = str.match(/#(.*?)\d+/g); //get str that starts with # and ends with digits
for (var i = 0; i < match.length; i++) {
  var keys = match[i].replace(/#|\d+/g, ''), // remove hash and numbers to match the data keys
    pos = match[i].replace(/\D/g, ''); // get the digits in str 
 newStr += data[keys][pos] + ' ';
}
console.log(newStr)
```

thanks for your help!

Comment: First of all assign `str` to `newStr` when you declare it `let newStr = str`, then just use replace on each match in your loop: `newStr = newStr.replace(match[i], data[keys][pos]);` instead of `newStr += data[keys][pos] + ' ';`

Comment: [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a `replacerFunction` is what you want to use.

Comment: Second question like this today [Loop over string, add words to string, return string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71658030/loop-over-string-add-words-to-string-return-string#comment126643214_71658030)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be to use [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a replacer function.

I use the regex `/#(\D+)(\d+)/g`. Matching `#`, followed by one or more non-digits (placed in capture group 1), followed by one or more digits (placed in capture group 2).

[image: regex diagram]

<sup>[Regexper](https://regexper.com/#%23%28%5CD%2B%29%28%5Cd%2B%29)</sup>

All capture groups are passed as arguments of the replacer function. The full match is passed as the first argument, capture group 1 as the second, etc.

Within the replacer function you can then access the value based on the captured attribute name and index.

```js
var data = {
  items: ["item", "HI", "item2"],
  moreitems: ["moreitem", "moreitem1", "HELLO"]
}
var str = "hey #items1 hey #moreitems2";

const result = str.replace(
  /#(\D+)(\d+)/g,
  (_match, attr, index) => data[attr][index]
);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: works! what does _match do? thanks

Comment: The first argument passed to the replacer function is the full match. You can use any parameter name that you want, like `match`, `foo`, `_`, etc. Since it holds the full match I've opted to call it `match`. The `_` I've place before it denotes that the parameter is intentionally not used. It's only there to shift other parameter assignments, making `attr` the second argument and `index` the third. Some people use just `_`, but I often prefer a more expressive name that at least tells you what it holds, even if we don't intent to use it.

Comment: The underscore code style is [common practice in Ruby](https://rubystyle.guide/#underscore-unused-vars) (which is the language I work most often with). But can also be found in [JavaScript linters](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars#argsignorepattern).

Answer (score 1):

you can use

- string.replace to replace the substr in the end of the process
- calculate the index in string array by recovered the last character of match string with `match[match.length - 1]`
- recover category of data to use by removing first and last character `category = match.slice(0, -1).substring(1);`

```js
var data = {
  items: ["item", "HI", "item2"],
  moreitems: ["moreitem", "moreitem1", "HELLO"]
}

var str = "hey #items1 hey #moreitems2";

var newStr = str;
var match = str.match(/#(.*?)\d+/g);
var index, category;
console.log(match);

match.forEach(match => {
  index = match[match.length - 1];
  category = match.slice(0, -1).substring(1);
  newStr = newStr.replace(match, data[category][index]);
});

console.log(newStr)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const dic       = {
  xxx: 'hello',
  yyy: 'world',
  zzz: 'peace'
}
const string    = 'hey! #xxx, #yyy! #zzz on you'
const newString = string.replace(/#\w+/g, item => dic[item.substring(1)])

console.log(string)
console.log(newString)
```